# preventing Array index out of bounds exception with coins

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out a way to separate a monetary value into quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies in the most efficient way.  This is currently my code:

```
public class CoinReader {
private static int amount = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    amount = (int)(Double.parseDouble(args[0])*100);
    System.out.println("Five: " + computeCoin(500));
    System.out.println("one: " + computeCoin(100) );
    System.out.println("Q : " + computeCoin(25) );
    System.out.println("D : " + computeCoin(10) );
    System.out.println("N : " + computeCoin(5) );
    System.out.println("P : " + computeCoin(1) );
}

public static int computeCoin(int cointValue) {
    int val = amount / cointValue;
    amount -= val * cointValue;
    return val;
}
```

}

I am currently getting an Array index out of bounds exception and I know it has something to do with the String array and the amount variable but I am trying to learn about arrays and I am trying to get this program to work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`args` array is empty, there is no element with index 0. You have to pass one command line argument to your program. When running from a command line make sure you pass a numeric value as an argument like this:

```
java CoinReader 113.25
```

Comment: I know about arguments but with the intent of my program, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `args[0]` and args appears to be empty.

How do you call your program ? You must have forgotten to pass a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It runs:

```
javac CoinReader.java
java CoinReader 1230
```

Ouput

```
Five: 246
one: 0
Q : 0
D : 0
N : 0
P : 0
```

Have fun to make it work correctly :-P

EDIT:

As already mentioned by the other guys the parameter `String args[]` refers to the arguments you provide on the command line when you run your compiled Program. You'll get an `ArrayOutOfBondsException` when you provide no argument as the array will be empty then.

When I say Have fun to make it work I mean that there seems to be an error in your `computeCoin` method as it won't output results for P, N, D and Q. But this is beyond your initial question.

SECOND EDIT:

It not just runs. It runs perfectly fine.

```
java CoinReader 10.11
```

Output:

```
Five: 2
one: 0
Q : 0
D : 1
N : 0
P : 1
```

Comment: Maybe help?  I am struggling to work around this problem but I am not understanding.